# Java DB / Apache Derby with Android

Tags: android, derby, javadb

Can I integrate Java DB or Apache Derby in my Android application? Or any inline or embedded database. Can anyone suggest code for it? 
I need some code because i have to make examples, not in theory.

Anyone knows if this databases is supported or not?

I thinks these are the inMobile DB, but i didn't find any related information in Google.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, Derby does not work in Android. See this issue for some more details: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-4458

Answer (score 2):

Android includes SQLite, so this is normal choice.

There is an embedded Java database that supports the Android platform: the [H2 database](http://h2database.com). However, support for Android is relatively new, and you probably shouldn't use it, unlike you really need features that SQLite doesn't support.